# Streamlining cleaning Tweet text with Stringr

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr, rtweet

I am learning about text mining and rTweet and I am currently brainstorming on the easiest way to clean text obtained from tweets. I have been using the method recommended on this [link](https://www.kaggle.com/lornamariak/tweet-mining-with-r)
to remove URLs, remove anything other than English letters or space, remove stopwords, remove extra whitespace, remove numbers, remove punctuations.

This method uses both gsub and tm_map() and I was wondering if it was possible to stream line the cleaning process using stringr to simply add them to a cleaning pipe line. [I saw an answer in the site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31348453/how-do-i-clean-twitter-data-in-r/59972658?noredirect=1#comment119924811_59972658) that recommended the following function but for some reason I am unable to run it.

```
clean_tweets <- function(x) {
        x %>%
        str_remove_all(" ?(f|ht)(tp)(s?)(://)(.*)[.|/](.*)") %>%
        str_replace_all("&amp;", "and") %>%
        str_remove_all("[[:punct:]]") %>%
        str_remove_all("^RT:? ") %>%
        str_remove_all("@[[:alnum:]]+") %>%
        str_remove_all("#[[:alnum:]]+") %>%
        str_replace_all("\\\n", " ") %>%
        str_to_lower() %>%
        str_trim("both")
    }
```

**Clean Solution:**

```
tweetsClean <- df %>% 
  mutate(clean = clean_tweets(text))
```

Lastly, is it possible to retain the emojis in order to count the frequency of which emojis are being used and potentially create custom sentiments for each?

**Emoji Solution:**

```
library(emo)
TopEmoji <- tweetsClean %>%
          mutate(emoji = ji_extract_all(text)) %>%
          unnest(cols = c(emoji)) %>%
          count(emoji, sort = TRUE) %>%
          top_n(5)
```

Once the text values are clean my process is to select relevant columns, add a line number to retain the tweet each word belongs to, and unnest the tokens

```
tweetsClean <- tweets %>%
    select(created_at,text) %>%
    mutate(linenumber = row_number()) %>%
    select(linenumber,everything()) %>%
    unnest_tokens(word, text) %>%
    anti_join(stop_words)
```

Following that I assign the desired sentiments and assign each line a value depending on the sum of the sentiments obtained with AFINN:

```
sentiment_bing <- get_sentiments("bing") 
sentiment_AFINN <- get_sentiments("afinn")

tweetsValue <- tweetsClean %>%
  inner_join(sentiment_bing) %>%
  inner_join(sentiment_AFINN) %>%
  group_by(linenumber,created_at) %>%
  mutate(TweetValue = sum(value))
```

Thanks for the pointers!

TestData:

```
df <- structure(list(created_at = structure(c(1622854597, 1622853904, 
1622853716, 1622778852, 1622448379, 1622450951, 1622777623, 1622853561, 
1622466544, 1622853192), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), text = c("@elonmusk can the dogefather ride @CumRocketCrypto into the night. #SpaceX @dogecoin https://twitter.com/", 
"@CryptoCrunchApp @CumRocketCrypto @vergecurrency @InuSanshu @Mettalex @UniLend_Finance @NuCypher @Chiliz @JulSwap @CurveFinance @PolyDoge Wrong this twitt shansu", 
"9am AEST Sunday morning!!!\nI will be hosting on the @CumRocketCrypto twitch channel!\n\nSo cum say Hi! https://twitter.com/", 
"@SamInCrypt1 @IamMars34147875 @DylanMcKitten @elonmusk @CumRocketCrypto Cumrocket <U+0001F4A6> https://twitter.com/", 
"@DK19663019 @CumRocketCrypto Oh hey, that's me! Did you grab one?", 
"@DK19663019 @CumRocketCrypto Thank you! <U+2764><U+FE0F>", "@CumRocketInfo @elonmusk @CumRocketCrypto Maybe he'd like to meet the CUMrocket models? https://twitter.com/", 
"@AerotyneToken @CumRocketCrypto Is there a way to make sure ones wallet ID is on the list?", 
"@AerotyneToken @CumRocketCrypto Does one have to attend the giveaway stream, or just hold 0.2 BNB of #CUMMIES and #ATYNE?\nAnd what happens if I bought about 0.2BNB each and the BNB price rises? Do I have to check every day if they're still worth at least 0.2?", 
"@Don_Santino1 @brandank_cr @PAWGcoinbsc @Tyga @CumRocketCrypto Massive bull flag. 10x is imminent!"
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your primary question, the `clean_tweets()` function is not working in the line "`Clean <- tweets %>% clean_tweets`" presumably because you are feeding it a dataframe. However, the function's internals (i.e., the `str_` functions) require character vectors (strings).

### cleaning issue

I say "presumably" here because I'm not sure what your `tweets` object looks like, so I can't be sure. However, at least on your test data, the following solves the problem.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(clean = clean_tweets(text))
```

If you just wanted the character vector back, you could also do

```
clean_tweets(df$text)
```

### emoji issue

Regarding the possibility of retaining emojis and assigning them sentiments, yes, I think you would proceed in essentially the way you have with the rest of the text: tokenize them, assign numeric values to each one, then aggregate.